# JavaFX Controller returns null

Tags: javafx, model-view-controller

I am trying to call the setTodos function which is in the OverviewController. When I try it this way it doesnt work, because controller is null. Anyone knows what the problem here could be? (don't know much about JavaFX...)

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/JavaTodoApp.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaTodoApp");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
        // access to controller
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/JavaTodoApp.fxml"));
        OverviewController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setTodos(this);
    }
```

Comment: can you show your fxml file, I guess you misset the controller in the fxml file

Comment: The controller isn’t created until the FXML is loaded. It doesn’t make sense to call methods on a controller which isn’t controlling anything.

Comment: In the FXML-File the Controller is connected. The Windows opens and then I try to get data in my ListView with the method setTodos. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the FXML from the `FXMLLoader` instance you create, not from the static method.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/JavaTodoApp.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    OverviewController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setTodos(this);

    primaryStage.setTitle("JavaTodoApp");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 500));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```